# React - html tags inside svg

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, render

I am making circle menu, so I use SVG to create a circle, and now I want to show a link with some image inside of part of the circle. How i can do it? My code -

```
render(){
    return(
       <svg id={"menuLevel" + index} width={200} height={200}>
          <path fill="white" stroke="rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" strokeWidth="2" d={"M"+width+","+width+" L"+previousX+", "+previousY+" A"+width+","+width+" 0 0,0 "+x+", "+y+" z"}></path>
      </svg>
    )
}
```

I tried something like this -

```
<path fill="white" stroke="rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" strokeWidth="2" d={"M"+width+","+width+" L"+previousX+", "+previousY+" A"+width+","+width+" 0 0,0 "+x+", "+y+" z"}>
     <foreignobject x="120" y="120" width="180" height="180">
         <Link ...><Image .../></Link>
     </foreignobject>
</path>
```

But it doesn't work, this foreign object have still 0 width and 0 height and content doesn't show.

**UPDATE**

I need to assign link component to all path objects

```
<svg id={"menuLevel" + index} width={width*2+2} height={width*2+2}>
                    {arr.map(function(item){
                        let angleInRadians = -item * Math.PI / 180.0;
                        let previousX =  x;
                        let previousY = y;
                        x = width + width * Math.cos(angleInRadians);
                        y = width + width * Math.sin(angleInRadians);
                        return(
                                <path fill="white" stroke="rgba(0,0,0,0.2)" strokeWidth="2" d={"M"+width+","+width+" L"+previousX+", "+previousY+" A"+width+","+width+" 0 0,0 "+x+", "+y+" z"}>
                                </path>
                        )
                    })}
                </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check it here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nseb1e1x/). Use `image` element to add the image to SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag

```
<svg width="5cm" height="4cm" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <circle x="0" y="0" r="200"></circle>
    <image xlink:href="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" x="0" y="0" height="200px" width="200px"/>
</svg>
```

Please note:

> If you do not set the x or y attributes, they will be set to 0.
>
> If you do not set the height or width attributes, they will be set to 0.
>
> Having a height or width attribute of 0 will disable rendering of the image.

---

### Update 1

Here is a working example to add a React component together with the image: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/tgebf8xc/3/). But I make the `Link` component as a sibling of the SVG, and then using `absolute` to position them. Not a perfect solution.

---

### Update 2

To make a path clickable: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/TmsrP/709/).

---

### Update 3

This is an image with clickable paths, integrated with ReactJS: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agongdai/tgebf8xc/8/):

```
var Link = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <a className="link" href={this.props.href} target="_blank">{this.props.children}</a>
  }
});

var Hello = React.createClass({ 
  render: function() {
    return <div id="container"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300px" height="300px">
     <Link href="http://www.google.com">
      <g transform="translate(100, 100)"><image href="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" x="0" y="0" height="200px" width="200px"/></g>
     </Link>
     <Link href="http://www.facebook.com">
     <g><image href="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" x="0" y="0" height="100px" width="100px"/></g>
     </Link>
</svg></div>
  }
});
```

Comment: And what if i need to use <Link ..>  instead of simple link...? I am writing in reactjs, and <Link..> allow me redirecting between my pages...

Comment: One problem, i have in one svg about 6+- objects(<path>), and i need to assign Link to all of them, but in this solution i can assign Link only to entire of svg.. no to certain <path>

Comment: U are totally awesome!! :D Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, please format the question more formally and start a new SO question to ask it. Better to give some live code base for other to start with. Other people may also help.