# React JSX - Filling an svg with an image

Tags: reactjs, svg, jsx, fill

I am trying fill a simple circle SVG with an image in React. The sources I found have not been helpful, for they don't seem to apply to JSX.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Anime from '../images/Anime.jpeg';


class Circle extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <svg height="300" width="300">
                    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill={Anime} />
                </svg>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Circle;
```

My first instinct was to tweak the `fill` attribute by either replacing the original color `="red"` with `={Anime}` or `=url("../images/Anime.jpeg")`, but neither worked.

(I know the path to the Anime image is correct, after testing it by rendering `<img src={Anime} alt={Anime}></img>` inside the div.

I see people using `<defs>` and `<pattern>` tags, as such (referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442833/svg-image-inside-circle)):

```
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">

  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
             viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="512" height="512" xlink:href="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/people-professions/512/Baby-512.png"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="5%" cy="40%" r="5%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
</svg>
```

But these tags don't seem to work in React / JSX; I keep getting this error when I try to use them: `Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag to bypass this warning.`

Is there a way around this? I want to be able to fit the following picture into a simple circle svg with a thick black border around it.

[image]

Comment: You could probably clip the image with `clip-path`. There's an example in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/), search for "Using clip-path with an SVG-defined <clipPath>".

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way and wanted to post / share it, in case anyone is here, looking at this post and wondering what the (one of the) solution(s) is!

Here is my final code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AnimeCropped from '../images/AnimeCropped.png';


class Circle extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <svg height="670" width="670">
                    <circle cx="350" cy="350" r="300" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
                    <image className='img-circle' xlinkHref={AnimeCropped} x='75.5' y="15" height="670" width="670"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Circle;
```

Essentially what I did was:

1. Crop the photo to be a circle. I could have followed *cubrr*'s recommendation above and clip-path'ed it (which is a great idea!), but instead - I just found and used a photo cropping tool online. I then named the newly-cropped picture "AnimeCropped" and saved it in the same directory.
2. Imported the picture into the component file and rendered via a `<image>` tag after the `<circle>` tag. It wasn't mentioned in my original question above, but I also hypothesized that inserting the image inside the circle might solve the problem. As such:

```
<svg height="670" width="670">
   <circle cx="350" cy="350" r="300" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="none">
      <img src={AnimeCropped} alt={AnimeCropped}/>
   </circle>
</svg>
```

But this didn't work.

In my final code, you'll see that the `<image>` tag comes after the `<circle>` tag, so technically, it's not really *inside* the circle, but just overlaying on top of it. Also note that I had to use `<image>`, not `<img>`. I'll have to do a bit of research on this, but `<img>` was giving me an error message.

Also important: In React, `xlink:href` won't work, but `xlinkHref` will! This really tripped me off, but I found this helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284688/react-html-tags-inside-svg).

3. Using classNames, I edited the size of the cropped picture in my App.css file.
4. Configured the x- and y- coordinates so that it *somewhat* fits perfectly in the middle of the circle.

That's it! Just wanted to post this for closure / help me review what I learned.