# React component inside an SVG element

Tags: reactjs, svg, components

I want to embed a custom react component inside an SVG but it's not working. Is it even allowed in an SVG? if not, are there workarounds?
Below is my code, trying to insert the Modal component:

```
<polygon
        id="Paris"
        <Modal show={show} handleClose={hideModal}>
          <p>Modal</p>
          <p>Data</p>
        </Modal>
        <button type="button" onClick={showModal}>
          open
        </button>
        stroke="#010101"
        fill="rgb(251, 106, 106)"
        stroke-width="2"
        stroke-miterlimit="10"
        points="1596.182,374.685 .../>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to display a popup when we click on a province inside an svg map.

Comment: Depends what <Model> actually does? Does it result in a <foreignObject> node being created with HTML children (good), or some random HTML being inserted without a <foreignObject> wrapper (bad)? HTML content in SVG must be wrapped in a <foreignObject> node,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Robert Longson's comment, I inserted the Modal component inside a foreignObject and it works. Still the Modal window needs to be adjusted manually as far as the x, y coordinates are concerned so that it pops up exactly over the clicked svg element:

```
 <foreignObject x="58%" y="6%" width="200px" height="250px">
        <Modal show={show} handleClose={hideModal}>
          <p style={{ padding: "10px" }}>Modal</p>
          <p>Data</p>
        </Modal>
</foreignObject>
```

Please note that you must set the x,y, height, width attributes for this to work, as documented in this answer [React - html tags inside svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284688/react-html-tags-inside-svg)

Answer (score 0):

For what your are trying to achieve, I will wrap svg's inside the modal. Something like this:

```
<Modal>
   <svg></svg>
</Modal>
```

In your modal component, make sure to display svg as children:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
      {props.children}
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Take a look in the doc for more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html